# How can i set the id of a link-to component in ember

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-2

I am trying to add ids to elements in Ember 2.4 to facilitate automated testing. However, elementId on link-to does not seem to be respected, and gets ignored.

Is there any way to force the id of a link-to component

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
{{link-to "route" id="elementId"}}
```

Not sure why I didn't get this when testing initially. I must have done something wrong when verifying this.